# Override a function's return value from another library

Tags: python, progress-bar

I'm using a library that calls a function, `some_func`, in a loop.

```
def main():
    xs = []
    for x in y:
        xs.append(some_func(x))
    return xs

def some_func(x):
    return some_data
```

I would like to intercept the `some_func` function's response and override it with my value.  For example:

```
def some_func(x):
    return my_func(some_data)
```

The purpose of doing this is so I can run some progress-hook to track  the time it will take to complete the process.

How can I do this without modifying the original library's source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a decorator, but instead of applying it with `@`, you directly wrap the target function. Something like this:

```
>>> import math
>>> def wrap_function(func):
...     def wrapper(x):
...         print('Called {0} with {1}'.format(func.__name__, x))
...         result = func(x)
...         print('Returned value is {0!r}'.format(result))
...         return result
...     return wrapper
... 
>>> math.sin = wrap_function(math.sin)
>>> r = math.sin(1.1337)
Called sin with 1.1337
Returned value is 0.905984636371863
>>> r
0.905984636371863
```

Given you now can do stuff before / after the call, you can implement time measurement and more.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, a decorator is what you should look into. Here is a snippet from [Andreas Jung](https://www.andreas-jung.com/contents/a-python-decorator-for-measuring-the-execution-time-of-methods). This allows you to add a @timeit decorator on any function you chose.

```
import time                                                

def timeit(method):

    def timed(*args, **kw):
        ts = time.time()
        result = method(*args, **kw)
        te = time.time()

        print '%r (%r, %r) %2.2f sec' % \
              (method.__name__, args, kw, te-ts)
        return result

    return timed

class Foo(object):

    @timeit
    def foo(self, a=2, b=3):
        time.sleep(0.2)

@timeit
def f1():
    time.sleep(1)
    print 'f1'

@timeit
def f2(a):
    time.sleep(2)
    print 'f2',a

@timeit
def f3(a, *args, **kw):
    time.sleep(0.3)
    print 'f3', args, kw

f1()
f2(42)
f3(42, 43, foo=2)
Foo().foo()
```